How can I upload property title to Idealista using API
I've to send property to idealista. According to idealista documentation https://feeds.idealista.com/v6/specs/properties.html I only found node (object key) to add description.
"descriptionText": {
"title": "description text",
"description": "line breaks are allowed using '\n' (wihout the quotes)",
"$ref": "../rules.json#/stringTo4000"
}

but not found any way to upload title.
